# getting the last characters in a string

Tags: jquery

i want to get the value of the **id** number in an  **A tag** , the tag looks like this:

```
<a class="ajaxRequest " href="/testSite/public/admin/forum/allocate/751"> Allocate </a>
```

i am able to get the values for the href using the following:

```
  $(".ajaxRequest").click(function(e){
           var str=$(".ajaxRequest").attr("href");        
            alert(str);
 });
```

However this give me the entire Href value. all i really want is the numbers at the end.

i realise that if i use the **substr();** i would be able to get the last digits. i.e

> var lastFive = id.substr(id.length - 5);

however, this is not helpful to me because i dont know how many digit will make up the Id.

**what i really need is to be able to get the last digit values from the query that ends after the last**  "/"

Comment: **1.** `str.split('/').pop()` **2.** `str.match(/\/(\d+)$/)[1]` **3.** `str.substring(str.lastIndexof('/') + 1)`

Comment: If you have control over the generation of the HTML: Add a `data-id="751"` atribute to the element. Then you can just use `$(this).data('id')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
"/testSite/public/admin/forum/allocate/751".match(/\d+$/)
```

This will match all digits from last

```
$(".ajaxRequest").attr("href").match(/\d+$/);
```

output:

```
["751"]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way if your url is same before id ;

```
    var str=$(".ajaxRequest").attr("href");     
    var res = str.split("allocate/");
    alert(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another way to achieve the same result.  Match against a number string between a `/` and `">`:

```js
var str = '<a class="ajaxRequest " href="/testSite/public/admin/forum/allocate/751"> Allocate </a>';
var numbers = str.match(/\/(\d*?)">/);
$('#output').html(numbers[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```